# Buffer and TypedArray conversion causes data mutation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, typed-arrays

I am loading remote assets over XHR and receive them as `arrayBuffers`. The underlying data is `float32` dependent.  I need to do some further operations on these array buffers like concatenation and merging. For these operations I was experimenting with the [buffer module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer).

I found that using the Buffer module and the underlying Uint8Array was changing the expected `float32` output

When instantiating the `TypedArray` with the `new Float32Array` constructor, the data is correct.

```
new Float32Array(action.payload.arrayBuffer)
Float32Array(9072) [-5, 35, -5, 255, 127, 128, 128, 1, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 1, -5, 34, -5, 255, 127, 128, 128, 1, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 1, -5, 35, -2, 255, 127, 128, 128, 1, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 1, -5, 34, -2, 255, 127, 128, 128, 1, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 1, -5, 35, -2, 255, 127, 128, 128, 1, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 1, -5, 34, -5, 255, 127, 128, 128, 1, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 0.2666666805744171, 1, -5, 38, -2, 255, 127, 128, 128, 2, 0.9411764740943909, 0.3686274588108063, 0.10980392247438431, 1, -5, 34, -2, 255, 127, 128, 128, 2, 0.9411764740943909, 0.3686274588108063, 0.10980392247438431, 1, -5, 38, 1, 255, …]
```

When initializing the `TypedArray` with the `from` method the data is empty. This is expected because the `from` method expects an iterable array, which `arrayBuffer` is not.

```
Float32Array.from(action.payload.arrayBuffer)
Float32Array []
```

When converting from a `Uint8Array` or a `Buffer` which uses an underlying `Uint8Array` the float data is mutated.

```
Float32Array.from(new Uint8Array(action.payload.arrayBuffer))
Float32Array(36288) [0, 0, 160, 192, 0, 0, 12, 66, 0, 0, 160, 192, 0, 0, 127, 67, 0, 0, 254, 66, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 128, 63, 137, 136, 136, 62, 137, 136, 136, 62, 137, 136, 136, 62, 0, 0, 128, 63, 0, 0, 160, 192, 0, 0, 8, 66, 0, 0, 160, 192, 0, 0, 127, 67, 0, 0, 254, 66, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 128, 63, 137, 136, 136, 62, 137, 136, 136, 62, 137, 136, 136, 62, 0, 0, 128, 63, 0, 0, 160, 192, …]

Float32Array.from(Buffer.from(action.payload.arrayBuffer))
    Float32Array(36288) [0, 0, 160, 192, 0, 0, 12, 66, 0, 0, 160, 192, 0, 0, 127, 67, 0, 0, 254, 66, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 128, 63, 137, 136, 136, 62, 137, 136, 136, 62, 137, 136, 136, 62, 0, 0, 128, 63, 0, 0, 160, 192, 0, 0, 8, 66, 0, 0, 160, 192, 0, 0, 127, 67, 0, 0, 254, 66, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 128, 63, 137, 136, 136, 62, 137, 136, 136, 62, 137, 136, 136, 62, 0, 0, 128, 63, 0, 0, 160, 192, …]
```

This difference in final output completely breaks my working pipeline that expects the `new Float32Array` output

I'm looking for an explanation and educational response on why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every single value the Uint8 array (view) holds is cast to a full Float32 value based on the view, not the underlying ArrayBuffer.

If you have a Uint8Array view that holds for example 4 entries:

```
Uint8 -> [1,2,3,4]
```

In the ArrayBuffer it will look something like this (ArrayBuffer is always a byte array):

```
0x01020304
```

What happens then is that when you convert the Uint8 view to Float32 view, the values in the *view* representation (i.e. [1,2,3,4]) is used, not the underlying ArrayBuffer, so those entries are simply converted to new entries but in a different *type* that still represent the same numbers [1,2,3,4] as the original view represented:

```
Float32 -> [1,2,3,4]   (each entry stored as 32-bit value)
```

And the new ArrayBuffer will look like (manually converted, but you'll get the idea) consisting of 4 bytes (32-bit) x 4 values the Float32 represents - also notice that floating point values are encoded in [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) format using 4 bytes for each number a Float32 type represents:

```
0x00003F80 00000040 00004040 00004080 (=1,2,3,4 as IEEE754 encoded floating point values)
```

You can also see this from the byte size of the new underlying ArrayBuffer (from the numbers in the question):

```
9,072 x 4 = 36,288 bytes
```

In order to get the result you'd expect you have to use the buffer directly via its `buffer` property:

```js
new Float32Array(uint8array.buffer);  // notice .buffer -> actual ArrayBuffer
```

This is by the way the same as you do in the first line in the question:

```js
new Float32Array(action.payload.arrayBuffer);
```

*Byte-order is one aspect here but since your numbers when used directly from XHR with a Float32 view is correct, this is probably not an issue in this case.*

So in short: there is no mutation taking place, but different types (via views) require different numbers of bytes as in this case, Uint8 a single byte from the underlying ArrayBuffer and Float32 4 bytes from the same, which means they will convert to different values as seem via the view.